# Postgres or Supabase Edge Function to fetch a user and its items

Tags: postgresql, flutter, supabase

I am using Flutter and I have three tables in Supabase:

- **user** (user_id, name)
- **user_items** (user_item_id, user_id, item_id)
- **items** (item_id, cost)

Is it possible to make one single query, maybe in an Edge Function, to get a result looking something like this:

```
{
  user_id: 1,
  name: 'John',
  items: [
    {item_id: 1, cost: 15},
    {item_id: 2, cost: 25}
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can query referenced tables right from flutter: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/select?example=query-referenced-tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres have a function called [json_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html)().

```
SELECT
  users.*,
  json_agg(items.*) as items
FROM
  users LEFT JOIN user_items ON users.user_id = user_items.user_id
  LEFT JOIN items ON user_items.item_id = items.item_id
GROUP BY
  users.*;
```